# JSoup HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405

Tags: jsoup, http-status-code-405

i would like connect to https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/ but with following code it does not work:

```
try
    {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();
        System.out.println(response.url());
        doc = response.parse();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Why i get status 405? How i could solve this problem?

Many thanks..

Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved

Changed useragent from "Mozilla" to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0)"