# Java - Jsoup HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to connect and retrieve the page title from [here](https://news.google.com/news/local/section/geo/Sammamish,%20WA%2098075,%20United%20States/Sammamish,%20Washington?ned=us&hl=en). The code works fine if I remove everything after ".com" from the link. The following code does not work:

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://news.google.com/news/local/section/geo/Sammamish,%20WA%2098075,%20United%20States/Sammamish,%20Washington?ned=us&hl=en")
        .data("query", "Java")
        .userAgent("Chrome")
        .cookie("auth", "token")
        .timeout(3000)
        .post();
    String title = doc.title();
    Log.d("hellomate", title);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("hellomatee", e.toString());
}
```

If the code worked, the title returned should be "Sammamish Washington - Google News".
The error returned from the code is: "org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=https://news.google.com/news/local/section/geo/Sammamish,%20WA%2098075,%20United%20States/Sammamish,%20Washington?ned=us&hl=en"

What does status 405 mean? Does Jsoup not allow the kind of url I used?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this q: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487157/jsoup-http-error-fetching-url-status-405&ved=0ahUKEwiT6sf2s8jVAhWMOxQKHWaSDmMQFggfMAE&usg=AFQjCNHU8QpL9rsnlQ2naxyoJPH-FQcuiA

Comment: 405 is "Method Not allowed" that means your POST is not allowed for this resource(URL). Try .get() if you only want to Receive something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status 405 is an http error code that means "Method Not allowed". You can find some documentation from microsoft on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications). As @Andreas said, you can fix this by changing `.post();` to `.get();`.

If you look at [the jsoup docs](https://jsoup.org/) under example, it shows you how you would probably want to structure your requests:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

Comment: Why do some urls work with post and others only with get?
Is there a way to get the headers of the page without using post?