# Jsoup return status code 405 (But it should accept POST)

Tags: jsoup, http-status-code-405

I am trying to upload data in the form using POST method in Jsoup and when I did that, it returns Status code 405.

I know 405 means method not supported. But the URL I provided contains a form for user to enter and submit data. So how can post method not be supported? Am I missing something else in Jsoup?

I had used Firefox inspect element feature to ensure the params (post data) and headers are followed, but it still don't work.

[image: Snippet of Request Header]

In addition, I had followed a supposed solution in [JSoup HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487157/jsoup-http-error-fetching-url-status-405) but it still didn't work.

```
Connection.Response postRes = Jsoup.connect("my-post-url")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0)")
                    .referrer("my-post-url")
                    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
                    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                    .header("Content-Length", Integer.toString(contentLength))
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("Host", "some-domain.org")
                    .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .data(paramMap)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();
```

The error I got from output:

org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=http://my-post-url

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the real url, but try to add the userAgent string of **your** browser and not a generic one (the one that appears at the last line of your screenshot).

Comment: Impossible to answer without the original URL. Just some general tips. Make sure your referrer makes sense and is the same as the original one. Use real user agent. Make sure you're posting correct cookies (maybe some of them are set in another ajax request by javascript). As a next step I'd use Wireshark to see if both requests (from the browser and using Jsoup) are same or similar on lower level.

Comment: Hi, as far as concern I had followed all header values from the real Firefox browser. I had even followed the number of post data and the value, but it still shows me 405. By any chance there is a security setting on the web server that detects and block bot?